# Why do I get a MemoryError in 64bit python when doing a replace within a 8MB file? (Bytes)

Tags: python, mitmproxy

I have a mitmproxy flow that contains multiple image files. The flow itself is in bytes. I am trying to dump the old images to files, then replace them within the flow with my own images.

However, I hit a Memory Error in Python and I don't understand why. The flow file itself is 8mb, the pictures I am trying to replace the old ones with are small, less then 100kb. There should be plenty of memory for that?

```
startList = list(re.finditer(b'\xff\xd8',flowContent))
x = 1
for a in startList:
    end = flowContent.find(b'\xff\xd9',a.start())
    fileContent = flowContent[a.start():end]
    fileName = 'image'+str(x)+".jpg"
    dumpfile = open('dump/'+fileName,'wb')
    dumpfile.write(fileContent)
    dumpfile.close()

    replace = open('replace/replace'+str(x)+'.jpg','rb')
    myImage = Image(replace)
    replace.close()

    nowTime = datetime.now()
    myImage.datetime = nowTime.strftime(DATETIME_STR_FORMAT)
    myImage.datetime_digitized = nowTime.strftime(DATETIME_STR_FORMAT)
    myImage.datetime_original = nowTime.strftime(DATETIME_STR_FORMAT)
    
    
    newImage = open('replace/replace'+str(x)+'U.jpg',"wb")
    newImage.write(myImage.get_file())
    newImage.close()
    
    replaceF = open('replace/replace'+str(x)+'U.jpg','rb')
    replaceContent = replaceF.read()
    replaceF.close()
    flowContent = flowContent.replace(fileContent,replaceContent)
    #flowContent = re.sub(fileContent,myImage.get_file(),flowContent)
     
    x = x+1
```

The error is on this line:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\SpecialK\flow.py", line 41, in <module>
    flowContent = flowContent.replace(fileContent,replaceContent)
MemoryError
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the exact output of the error including stack trace.

Comment: Done, though that error is the full traceback